# PHP/MSSQL Connection

Tags: php, sql-server

I have the following code that doesn't seem to make the connection to the MSSQL db:

```
<?php
$serverName = "SEVER_NAME\sqlexpress"; //serverName\instanceName

$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"TESTDB", 
                          "UID"=>"SERVER_NAME\Administrator", 
                          "PWD"=>"Password123");

$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn )
{
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}
else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

?>
```

The message reads that login failed for user SERVER_NAME\Administrator, but that's what I see in the SQL Server Management Studio when I check the DB properties. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "login failed" means you DID connect, but with incorrect credentials. do you have a user named "Administrator" in the db? just because a windows-level account exists of that name, doesn't mean it'll work inside mssql as well.

Comment: Thanks @Marc B, I double-checked this. It is using the SERVER_NAME\Administrator account for the DB and re-confirmed when seeing the connection properties in SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 0):

The login name looks suspiciously like that SQL server is using Windows authentication. If this script and the SQL server are on the same machine, try omitting UID and PWD entirely, as per the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296161(v=SQL.105).aspx).

> If values for the UID and PWD keys are not specified in the optional $connectionInfo parameter, the connection will be attempted using Windows Authentication.

Comment: Thanks @Jacob See; I do use Windows Authentication for this db. I removed, as you suggested, the UID and PWD, but now the message reads: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.